# MongoDB read performance dependency

Tags: performance, mongodb

I'm playing around with MongoDB 2.4.5 and I'm interested in the reading/querying performance.
Say I have two very large collections (about 1,5000,000 documents each). The documents do have about 40 fields. They only differ in exactly one field, therefore they do have the same indexes and so on.
One collection does have a field `Body` where a `string` is stored. This `string` can be rather large as it represents the content of a news item. The other collection does not have that field.

My question now is which of the two collections is faster to be queried, sorted and so on. Writing is no issue here.

So what is more serious for querying a MongoDB collection. The sheer amount of items within a collection or the size of the items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to do it yourself:

```
1. db.coll1.find({}).explain()

2. db.coll2.find({}).explain()
```

and after your could measure the difference of performance between two different queries.

Comment: I'm trying this (on a locally installed MongoDB) but it always returns values with `0`, e.g. `"millis" : 0` etc. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm also trying `db.col1.find().limit(50)` which should return the first 50 items. But the MongoDB shell (mongo.exe) shows nothing.

Comment: Ok I got it... started the shell wrongly... Have to add IP, port and database name, e.g. `mongo --shell 127.0.0.1:27017/myDatabaseName`.

Comment: Thx. I now have reliable measurement data. To finally answer my question. The larger collection (that with the `Body` field). Is slightly slower. 364 ms instead of 356 ms, which is 2.2% slower.